# I am trying to create a react app but it gives this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, runtime-error

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\MongoDb\mongosh-1.0.1-win32-x64\mongosh-1.0.1-win32-x64\bin      
npm ERR! path C:\Arya\web development\react-project-first
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\MongoDb\mongosh-1.0.1-win32-x64\mongosh-1.0.1-win32-x64\bin ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yoges\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-20T17_12_07_619Z-debug.log
```

My node and npm versions are up to date.
I tried reinstalling npm and tried installing a module to make sure it is working but it's showing  the same error.

And in my package.json when I click debug this is what it [shows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d29GW.png)

Can someone tell me what to do?

Comment: Your npm is not installed correctly. Reinstall it

Comment: how would I correctly install it? I already did uninstall and reinstall it. Also, it comes packaged with node so I don't really need to install it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it started working again. The path of the ComSpec was changed for some reason and also in the environment variables the MongoDB was messing so had to delete that too.

Answer (score 0):

you should uninstall it.

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app.`
and then try again, it happens sometimes if you have an old version installed.

Comment: I did that and it doesn't work, I already reinstalled it a bunch of times.